# How To Cast Ilist To ArrayList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting

Can I Cast `IList` into `ArrayList`?

if yes what should I do?

```
IList alls = RetrieveCourseStudents(cf);
ArrayList a = (ArrayList)alls;
```

Is that correct?

is has error:

> Unable to cast object of type

Comment: What type does `RetrieveCourseStudents` return? Why do you need to cast it to an `ArrayList`? You shouldn't use `ArrayList` in new code but generic collections.

Comment: public EntityCollection<CourseStudent> RetrieveCourseStudents(CF cf);

Comment: Why do you want to cast that to an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Becaouse Ilist not Sort Method But Arraylist is Have Sort Method

Comment: And `IEnumerable<T>` has `OrderBy` already (a LINQ extension method). Just use that on the result of `RetrieveCourseStudents` - and use `var` instead of `IList`.

Comment: Please Told me With Example.....Tanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all about polymorphism.
ArrayList is an implementation from the **Interface IList**.

```
 IList iList = new ArrayList();
```

The static type from the variable iList is **IList** but it references an ArrayList Object!

There is no real casting from IList to ArrayList because you can not instantiate/create Object from Interface or abstract Class.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, you should consider using generic collections instead

```
List<Student> students = RetrieveCourseStudents(cf).Cast<Student>().ToList()
```

Answer (score 4):

You'd only be able to cast `alls` to an [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) if it already is an `ArrayList`, i.e. if the object returned by `RetrieveCourseStudents` is an `ArrayList`.

If it isn't then you need to create a new object, luckly `ArrayList` has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83h9yskw.aspx) that can do this: `new ArrayList(RetrieveCourseStudents(cf))`

---

It's worth noting that you should be using generics (such as [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)) instead of `ArrayList` now, so unless you need to interact with some old code that can't be updated, i'd stay away from it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 
we can cast IList to ArrayList only if RetrieveCourseStudents(cf) returns type of Arraylist.

for example

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList test1 = GetList();
            IList test2= GetIList();
            ArrayList list1 = (ArrayList)test1; // Fails
            ArrayList list2 = (ArrayList)test2;  // Passes

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static IList GetIList()
        {
            return new ArrayList();
        }

        private static IList GetList()
        {
            return new CustomList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you commented that you simply want to order the returned list (which in another comment you say is of type `EntityCollection<CourseStudent>`) - you do not need to cast to an `ArrayList` but simply use the value directly.

You can use the [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) LINQ extension method (and the variable type you use - `IList` is also not suitable).

This would work for your needs (where `CourseStudentProperty` is a property of `CourseStudent`):

```
var alls = RetrieveCourseStudents(cf);
var orderedAlls = alls.OrderBy(cs => cs.CourseStudentProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace MyILists
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<int> intArrayList = new ArrayList().ToIList<int>();
        intArrayList.Add(1);
        intArrayList.Add(2);
        //intArrayList.Add("Sample Text"); // Will not compile

        foreach (int myInt in intArrayList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Number : " + myInt.ToString());
        }
        Console.Read();
    }      
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> ToIList<T>(this ArrayList arrayList)
    {
        IList<T> list = new List<T>(arrayList.Count);
        foreach (T instance in arrayList)
        {
            list.Add(instance);
        }
        return list;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..

Answer (score 0):

just use this simple code :)

```
(From x In list).ToArray
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the LINQ Union extension.

*Note that you can combine any type of IEnumerable with this technique (Array, IList, and so on), so you don't need to worry about an "Add" method. You do have to understand that LINQ is producing immutable results, so you then need to use "ToList()", "ToDictionary()", or whatever, if you want to subsequently manipulate the collection.*

```
    var list =
        (IList<Student>) new [] 
        {
            new Student {FirstName = "Jane"}, 
            new Student {FirstName = "Bill"},
        };

    var allStudents = list.Union(
        new [] {new Student {FirstName = "Clancey"}})
           .OrderBy(s => s.FirstName).ToList();

    allStudents[0].FirstName = "Billy";

    foreach (var s in allStudents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FirstName = {0}", s.FirstName);
    }
```

Output:

```
FirstName = Billy
FirstName = Clancey
FirstName = Jane
```