# BindingList to ArrayList gives runtime error

Tags: c#, vb.net, arraylist, bindinglist

I am trying to use an ArrayList, and bind it to a BindingList...

If I try to put it in (I have Option Strict On), I get a suggestion for casting that I implemented -

Yet I keep getting a runtime error no matter what I try.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ArrayList' to type 'IList`
```

The code:

```
Dim myBoundList As System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of something) =
    New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of something)
      (CType(myArrayList, System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of something)))
```

I have tried to insert .ToArray...

The accepted answer at the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/8770832/1217150 does exactly the same thing (even though the intent is the opposite), and I have tried it... (I mean, creating an IList item, and assigning

```
IList iList = new ArrayList();
```

It gives me the same error...

I am using VB.NET, but c# would help too. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out using the generic `List` class (a .NET type) rather than using the non-generic `ArrayList`. I suspect this might be related to your problem. It's probably trying to cast the non-generic `ArrayList` to an `IList<T>` (the **generic** version of IList).

Comment: I found the answer with the help of another Stack overflow question:
  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3556004/1217150

        Dim StronglyTypedList = OriginalArrayList.Cast(Of MyType().ToList()      Thank you for suggesting the right path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add the array list as items to the listbox, you can use the following code:

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new array list.
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    // Add items to the array list
    list.Add("MyItem1");
    list.Add("MyItem2");
    list.Add("MyItem3");

    //Set the data source of the listbox as the array list
    listBox1.DataSource = list;
}
```